# Issue with multiple logistical regresstion code with multiple predictors

Tags: r, regression, analysis

I am trying to perform multiple logistical regression with some of the variables that came out as statistically significant for a diseased conditions with univariate analysis. We took the cut off for that as p<0.2 since our sample size was ~300. I made a new dataframe for these variables

```
regression1df <- data.frame(dgfcriteria, recipientage, ESRD_dx,bmirange,graftnumber, dsa_class_1, organ_tx, transfuse01m, transfuse1yr, readmission1yr, citrange1, switrange, anastamosisrange, donorage, donorgender, donorcriteria, donorionotrope, intubaterange, kdpirange, kdrirange, eptsrange, proteinuria, terminalurea, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I'm using variables to predict for disease condition, which is DGF (dgfcriteria==1), and non-disease is no DGF (dgfcriteria==0).

Here is structure of the data.

[image]

When I tried to run the entire list of variables with the glm code I got:

```
predictors1 <- glm(dgfcriteria ~.,
data = predictors1df,
family = "binomial" )
```

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels.

But when I run it with only some of the variables of the dataframe, there is an output.

```
predictors1 <- glm(dgfcriteria ~ recipientage + ESRD_dx + bmirange + graftnumber + dsa_class_1 + organ_tx + transfuse01m + transfuse1yr +  readmission1yr +citrange1 +switrange + anastamosisrange+ donorage+ donorgender + donorcriteria + donorionotrope,
data = predictors1df,
family = "binomial" )
```

This output looks really strange though with alot of NAs.

[image]

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: It is not specifically that you have gone wrong, what it typically means when you have the singularity message and NA values is that you have variables that are not linearly independent...meaning their predictiveness is accounted for by other variables without NA values for coefficients. What you can do is remove whole sets of variables when the contain NA for most level.

Comment: You should probably use a correlation matrix to assess to what extent your variables are related prior to modeling.

Comment: @sconfluentus I already ran the univariate analysis to measure association for about 500 variables and these were the ones with p value <0.2. I think I'll drop some variables and just use the significant ones for modelling.

Comment: It is likely that not all of the variable, but just some categories in some variables are highly correlated to other variables. And it seems that you have created bands of some continuous variables, this can introduce problems some times. I think if you were to read a chapter or two on regressions, you might find some of the answers you are looking for in there. *A Modern Approach to Regression with R* by Simon Sheather has good chapters on Variable Selection, Logistic Regression & Serially Correlated Data. Those chapters should get you headed in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your data structure, you've got a lot of missing values. Quite a few of your variables look to have only 2 or 3 non-missing values in the first 10 rows. When you run regression on data with missing values, the default is to drop all rows that have *any* missing values.

Apparently some of your data has bad overlaps, so that when all the rows with missing values are dropped (see `na.omit(your_data)` for what is left over), some variables only have one level left and are therefore no longer fit for regression. Of course, when you only use some variables, fewer rows will be dropped and you may be in a better situation.

So, you'll have to decide what to do with your missing values. This should depend on your goals and your understanding of the *reasons* for missingness. Common possibilities include omission, imputation, creating new "missing" levels, and taking level of missingness into account in your variable selection.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. Unfortunately, this is retrospective clinical data so I have to make do with what's already been collected because we can't go back in time to collect those blood samples. Following your suggestion, I split the dataframe and ran the models again with around 3-4 variables. So now I have 3 models. It seems the combination of variables matter though because depending on which model I place recipient age in, it may or may not come up as significant... Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Because some of your variables are more or less correlated with age. Let's say `BMI` and `age` are correlated, and both are correlated with your outcome. A model with either `BMI` or `age` will show that variable as significant. A model with both will have trouble distinguishing between the two. This should be covered in any textbook or course on multiple regression.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest picking up a good book on regression... based on your subject matter and your issues, I'd recommend Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies.